# Car engine starts only for a fraction of a second and doesn't anymore?

Tags: engine, starting

Recharged the car battery, dashboard lights all on, starter motor producing the starting sound. Engine not starting. After seeing [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/car-suddenly-decides-to-not-crank) question, I cleaned the solenoid brushes and at the first turn of the key, the engine starts for half a second and stops. Because of continuously trying to start the car, the battery seems to be going down. Tried pushing the car to start it, but it didn't.

My dad says the problem may be because no petrol is reaching the engine (which may be true because it's been more than a week since I've started the car). Plus, one engine bore is worn out because of which engine oil hits the spark plug, causing misfire. It's been more than six months since I've given it for servicing (spark plug changed) and I use the car only about twice a month.

Is the solution to find the tube that brings petrol to the engine and pour some petrol into it (I hear people do it when air gets into the pipe)?

p.s: Also, as a secondary question I'd like to know a neutral opinion of how often should a person give a car for servicing (car more than a decade old) when it has a misfiring problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that a rat chewed up the petrol tube. The mechanic opened the bonnet, and tried to suck out some petrol and nothing came out. Then he got underneath the car and saw the chewed tube. That's why no petrol was reaching the engine. Darn rats!

Answer (score 3):

Try getting a jump start from another vehicle - it may be the starter motor is old, or your battery is just not giving enough current. This is probably the most likely problem - one drive a month may not be enough to keep a decent charge in your battery, so a few solutions:

- take it out more often
- use a trickle charger
- give it a good blast when you do take it out

Pouring petrol in anywhere other than the petrol tank is not generally something you want to try. It can help in certain circumstances, yes, but also can cause other problems.

I get my car serviced every 10000 miles, or at least once a year (but some cars are happy with 20000 so check your service manual)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a misfire, you should service it then.  There aren't any cars newer than 10 years old in my driveway and none of them misfire.  When not having problems you should stick to what the manual says.

Comment: Well, I wanted to try and get the car running to take it for a servicing (instead of having to call a mechanic home), so I'd just like to get it to start first.

Answer (score 1):

If your car is not starting it means there could be three reasons
1. low petrol
2. battery low
3. some fault in starter
If battery is low, push your car upto 5 to 10 km/h with holding the clutch and in 2nd gear. When you have speed, leave the clutch and step on the accelerator. The engine will start easily or else u want to change the battery or recharge it.

Petrol block means You will have a plug switch. It will look like we can pull it little bit it will be in driver seat near by steering wheel.

Weather not be means give ignition by scrolling the key to start position and keep on stamping the accelerator for a min and then give start it will start, if not means you want to give service to workshop